# "x of n" in StringTemplate from a single int/count

Tags: stringtemplate

I'm trying to print out generate shipping labels, and I know how many I want.  So given that I know `n`, how do I print "`x` of `n`" for x=1 to n?

What I'm wanting to do is have an expansion template that will take `n` and provide the `x` and `n` variables to the template I shall pass (StringTemplate is a functional-type templating language, so this sort of thing is it's strength).

Sorry about not having a structure yet, but I'm just having thinking inside the framework...

Basically, given :

```
$xOfn(n=3)$
```

I should get

```
1 of 3
2 of 3
3 of 3
```

The real template that I'd like to use is something like

```
<div class="label">
   <div class="labelInfo">$info$</div>
   <div class="item">$x$ of $n$</div>
</div>
```

Where I would use something like `$xOfn(n=someInt,template="myTemplate")$` (the above template is called myTemplate)

Comment: Can you put add details (input data, desired output, etc) ?

Answer (score 0):

How about `$objects:{ o | $i$ of $length(objects)$}$`

Comment: There are plenty of examples of this on the site... but I do not have a collection - I have an integer (that I want to do a list expansion on). Consider also the case where you have an article that is 4 pages long, and you are on page 2 - how would you go about formatting the page links along with previous and next?